# What (if any) games are unsolvable?

Tags: game-theory

[Some games have been solved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game) (checkers, tic-tac-toe), some games *can* be solved (Chess, Go); what I want to know is: are there any game which *cannot* be solved?

Supposing you had an infinite amount of computing power and could writing an infinitely large book containing all games states, are there any games which would still be unsolvable? Is it just any game with chance (cards, dice, tiles etc)? I’ve heard backgammon has been solved though, so maybe it’s more complicated than that.

Comment: Conway's Game of Life

Comment: It's known that [Magic: The Gathering is Turing complete](https://www.toothycat.net/~hologram/Turing/), so that seems like a plausible candidate here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax

Comment: You'll have to be very specific about your definitions in order to answer this kind of question.  Otherwise,it's not even possible to determine which games are finite in the sense of which games are guaranteed to end in a finite number of moves.  There are some tricky constructions out there.